# dialog box confirmation inside custom dialog box

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

Hello I have the following dialog box

```
Object[] options = {"10 MINS: " + Utility.NF.format(price1),
    "30 MINS: " + Utility.NF.format(price2),
    "1 HOUR: " + Utility.NF.format(price3),
    "ALL DAY: " + Utility.NF.format(price4)
    };

int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(new JFrame(),
        "Please select the credit you wish to add \n WARNING: CREDIT CAN NOT BE REFUNDED",
         "Credit selection",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
        null,     //do not use a custom Icon
        options,  //the titles of buttons
        options[0]); //default button title
        return n;
```

My question is, is there a way of adding a yes no confirmation inside of my custom dialog box.

For example, if the user selects '10mins...' inside my custom dialog box, then another simple YES/NO confirmation dialog pops up.

I've searched for other questions but found none where a yes/no dialog would appear inside of a custom dialog box.

Cheers,

Comment: See [*Stopping Automatic Dialog Closing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input), open the new `JOptionPane` in your `PropertyChangeListener`, and edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.